# Leitura da porta serial no delphi xe8

Tags: delphi

Qual componente eu uso no delphi xe8 para fazer a leitura da porta COM, já vi que no delphi 7 tem a `tcomport` queria saber para o delhi xe qual seria?

Answer (score 1):

Existe o TComPort para as versões XE também. [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/)

Comment: @Maurício Souza se a resposta foi útil para você, favor aceitá-la para que outros usuários possam se beneficiar do conhecimento compartilhado. Abraço.